# How to customise laravel chart

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project and I used laravel chart. But unfortunately, my chart is of one color and I do not how to customize it

Here is the chart conroller

```
 use App\Charts\UserChart;
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(5);

        $today_users = User::whereDate('created_at', today())->count();
        $yesterday_users = User::whereDate('created_at', today()->subDays(1))->count();
        $users_2_days_ago = User::whereDate('created_at', today()->subDays(2))->count();

        $chart = new UserChart;
        $chart->labels(['2 days ago', 'Yesterday', 'Today']);
        $chart->dataset('Users', 'pie', [$users_2_days_ago, $yesterday_users, $today_users]);
        return view('admin.index', compact(['users', 'chart']));

    }
```

If anyone could help, please, do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change color via

```
$chart->color("rgb(255, 99, 132)")
```

Or change the background color via

```
$chart->backgroundcolor("rgb(255, 99, 132)");
```